# Find max date less than today

Tags: python, pandas

I’m trying to locate the current date (in this example the date was 1/15/2021) across all columns and return the result in the “current status” column.

The logic behind this in excel is max(if(B2:E2<=“1/15/2021”,B2:E2))

I’m not sure how to work this out through python
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Get all the values into a list, filter it for values after your date, then select the max value

Comment: Are you just looking for a column that has the current date?

Comment: @fthomson, Yes basically

Comment: check my answer :) I wouldn't bother with the conditional logic unless there is a need

Comment: No that just gives me today’s date. Not the latest date that is greater than or equal to today’s date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do this

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
df['current status'] = dt.now().date()
```

this would be the easiest way